# I can't pass splash to another activity

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, splash-screen

I have program that has splassh page I used intent to pass splash activity to my main activity folder but when I run my program it stop after my splash 
and here is my splash class and manıfest xml and my logcat

```
package com.tesbih;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){

             public void run(){
                 try{
                    sleep(5000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){

                    e .printStackTrace();

                }finally{

   Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent ("com.tesbih.TESBIHMAINACTIVITY");
   startActivity(openStartingPoint);

                }
            }   
        };

        timer.start();
    }
  }
```

and following my manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.tesbih"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tesbih.TesbihMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TESBIHMAINACTIVITY" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.tesbih.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


  </application>

  </manifest>
```

moreover here is my logcat

> 02-23 20:33:40.713: E/AndroidRuntime(5683)android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:     No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.tesbih.TESBIHMAINACTIVITY }

Comment: Is the activity in your manifest?

Comment: decalre TESBIHMAINACTIVITY in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy and paste the that shown in below

```
package com.tesbih;

 import android.R;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){

            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(3000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }finally{

                    Intent i = new Intent (Splash.this,TesbihMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity (i);                          
                }
           }     
        };
        timer.start();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

start your activity like this,

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent (Splash.this,TesbihMainActivity.class);
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

instead of Timer, you can use handler for splash as well.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TesbihMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close splash
                finish();
            }
}, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:name="com.tesbih.TesbihMainActivity"`
You have above in manifest so you must change 
`("com.tesbih.TESBIHMAINACTIVITY");` to `("com.tesbih.TesbihMainActivity");` in splash.java